# Understanding performance of a tailrec annotated recursive method in scala

Tags: scala

Consider the following method - which has been verified to conform to the proper `tail recursion` :

```
  @tailrec
  def getBoundaries(grps: Seq[(BigDecimal, Int)], groupSize: Int, curSum: Int = 0, curOffs: Seq[BigDecimal] = Seq.empty[BigDecimal]): Seq[BigDecimal] = {
    if (grps.isEmpty) curOffs
    else {
      val (id, cnt) = grps.head
      val newSum = curSum + cnt.toInt
      if (newSum%50==0) { println(s"id=$id newsum=$newSum") }
      if (newSum >= groupSize) {
        getBoundaries(grps.tail, groupSize, 0, curOffs :+ id) // r1
      } else {
        getBoundaries(grps.tail, groupSize, newSum, curOffs) // r2
      }
    }
  }
```

This is running *very* slowly - about 75 loops per second.  When I hit the stacktrace (a nice feature of `Intellij`) almost every time the line that is currently being invoked is the second tail-recursive call `r2`. That fact makes me suspicious of the purported "scala unwraps the recursive calls into a `while` loop". If the unwrapping were occurring then why are we seeing so much time in the invocations themselves?

Beyond having a properly structured tail recursive method are there other considerations to get a recursive routine have performance approaching a direct iteration?

Comment: How much faster was direct iteration in this case? Can you post the code so we can see what the differences might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is  *not* in the recursion but instead in the **array manipulation** .  With the following testcase it runs at about *200K recursions per second*

```
  type Fgroups = Seq[(BigDecimal, Int)]
  test("testGetBoundaries") {
    val N = 200000
    val grps: Fgroups = (N to 1 by -1).flatMap { x => Array.tabulate(x % 20){ x2 => (BigDecimal(x2 * 1e9), 1) }}
    val sgrps = grps.sortWith { case (a, b) =>
      a._1.longValue.compare(b._1.longValue) < 0
    }
    val bb = getBoundaries(sgrps, 100 )
    println(bb.take(math.min(50,bb.length)).mkString(","))
    assert(bb.length==1900)
  }
```

My *production data sample* has a similar number of entries (`Array` with 233K rows ) but runs at *3 orders of magnitude more slowly*.  I am looking into the *tail* operation and other culprits now.

**Update** The following reference from `Alvin Alexander` indicates that the `tail` operation should be v fast for **immutable** collections - but deadly slow for long *mutable* ones - including Array's !

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/understanding-performance-scala-collections-classes-methods-cookbook

[image]

[image]

**Wow!**  I had no idea about the performance implications of using `mutable` collections in scala!

**Update** By adding code to convert the `Array` to an (`immutable`) `Seq` I see the 3 orders of magnitude performance improvement on the production data sample:

```
val grps = if (grpsIn.isInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[_]] || grpsIn.isInstanceOf[Array[_]]) {
  Seq(grpsIn: _*)
} else grpsIn
```

The (now *fast* ~200K/sec) final code is:

```
  type Fgroups = Seq[(BigDecimal, Int)]  
  val cntr = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
  @tailrec
  def getBoundaries(grpsIn: Fgroups, groupSize: Int, curSum: Int = 0, curOffs: Seq[BigDecimal] = Seq.empty[BigDecimal]): Seq[BigDecimal] = {
    val grps = if (grpsIn.isInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[_]] || grpsIn.isInstanceOf[Array[_]]) {
      Seq(grpsIn: _*)
    } else grpsIn

    if (grps.isEmpty) curOffs
    else {
      val (id, cnt) = grps.head
      val newSum = curSum + cnt.toInt
      if (cntr.getAndIncrement % 500==0) { println(s"[${cntr.get}] id=$id newsum=$newSum") }
      if (newSum >= groupSize) {
        getBoundaries(grps.tail, groupSize, 0, curOffs :+ id)
      } else {
        getBoundaries(grps.tail, groupSize, newSum, curOffs)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You won't get sensible performance figures with `println` in your code. Also, what is `Fgroups`?

Comment: the println's at the given 1/500 frequency are fine. I'll de-obfuscate the `Fgroups`

Comment: Using your test data I don't see any performance improvement with your code. Also, your test for  `grpsIn.isInstanceOf[Array[_]]` is pointless because `Array` does not extend `Seq`.

Comment: The check *is* required - and does give the 200K in about 1 sec for the 1000x perf improvement on my production sample test data - which I obviously can not show. I might improve the provided  test data - since apparently it does not adequately reflect the production sample.

Comment: Hmm.. what class library are you using, and what version of Scala? In scala 2.12.4 `scala.Array` does not extend `scala.Seq` so an instance of `scala.Seq` can never be an instance of `scala.Array`.

Comment: How does my version perform on your data?

Comment: I've lost a bit of interest here  - since your answer is a subset of mine yet you downvoted mine . I'm not "feelin it" here in terms of equitableness.

Comment: Your answer has special code to detect specific subtypes of `Seq` whereas mine is general and works for all subtypes of `Seq`, so it is hard to see how mine is a subset of yours! It also runs faster than yours, which I think is the point of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176813/discussion-between-javadba-and-tim).

Answer (score 2):

The performance will depend on the underlying type of the `Seq`.

If it is `List` then the problem is appending (`:+`) to the `List` because this gets very slow with long lists because it has to scan the whole list to find the end.

One solution is to *prepend* to the list (`+:`) each time and then `reverse` at the end. This can give very significant performance improvements, because adding to the start of a list is very quick.

Other `Seq` types will have different performance characteristics, but you can convert to a `List` before the recursive call so that you know how it is going to perform.

---

Here is sample code

```
def getBoundaries(grps: Seq[(BigDecimal, Int)], groupSize: Int): Seq[BigDecimal] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(grps: List[(BigDecimal, Int)], curSum: Int, curOffs: List[BigDecimal]): List[BigDecimal] =
    if (grps.isEmpty) curOffs
    else {
      val (id, cnt) = grps.head
      val newSum = curSum + cnt.toInt

      if (newSum >= groupSize) {
        loop(grps.tail, 0, id +: curOffs) // r1
      } else {
        loop(grps.tail, newSum, curOffs) // r2
      }
    }

  loop(grps.toList, 0, Nil).reverse
}
```

This version gives 10x performance improvement over the original code using the test data provided by the questioner in his own answer to the question.

Comment: The chart showing the relative performance of different implementations is included in my answer - i'll make it bigger since maybe it were hard to read. Using a `Seq` did do the trick performance wise.